# Internal Server Error: missing method or closure

Tags: templating, matrix, error-message, error, error-handling

Receiving the standard error:

> Craft\MatrixBlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or
>   closure named "sectionArticles".

The problem is that this error doesn't make sense. Here is why:

1. I have a newsletter template with the block 'sectionArticles'
2. It lists entries from 3 different sections
3. These 3 sections do not have a block 'sectionArticles' nor a reference to it in their templates.
4. If I click on a link that leads to the url for these entries, I receive the above error
5. If I copy and paste the url into a new tab everything is fine
6. This only recently started happening. In other words, old issues of the newsletter are fine

Help?

Here is code for referring template:

```
{% for block in entry.connectionsContent %}
  {% switch block.type %}
    {% case "connectionsTextOnly" %}
      <div class="{{ block.backgroundColor }} page-section">
        <div class="row">
          {% set asset = block.sectionImage.first() %}
          {% if asset %}
            <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns large-push-9 medium-push-8">
              <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
            </div>
            <div class="large-9 medium-8 small-12 columns large-pull-3 medium-pull-4">
          {% else %}
            <div class="small-12 columns">
          {% endif %}
              {{ block.sectionText }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% default %}
      {% set entries = block.sectionArticles %}
      {% if entries | length %}
        <div class="{{ block.backgroundColor }} page-section article-grid">
          <div class="row large-up-4 medium-up-2" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium">
            {% for entry in entries %}
              {% if entry.section.handle == "news" %}
                {% include 'news/_includes/feed' %}
              {% elseif entry.section.handle == "pages" %}
                {% include 'pages/_includes/feed' %}
              {% elseif entry.section.handle == "events" %}
                {% include 'events/_includes/feed' %}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

The feed templates are just links and display fine.

The errors occurs on the events/_entry, news/_entry and pages/_entry templates. There is no references of the block 'sectionArticles' in those templates.

One more thing: the error only happens on scheduled entries, where the Post Date is in the future, after the Post Date has arrived.

Comment: can you please share the template code that seems to be throwing this error?

Comment: How is `block` getting defined in your template?  Are you looping through all of your Matrix blocks?

Comment: I updated above to include the block and switch. After further research, it turns out that the error is thrown only when a "connectionsTextOnly" block exists.

Still doesn't answer the question of why it throws the error after you leave

Comment: By using `{% default %}`, you're saying that every block not named `connectionsTextOnly` is going to have a `sectionArticles` field in it... is that the case?

Comment: correct. There are only two block types.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for taking a look. I forgot that I had implemented something on the receiving templates that allowed you to navigate between articles from the newsletter, if the referral url was the newsletter. After I implemented the text only block, I forgot to change this to ignore those blocks.